# How to detect all keypresses after pressing a %

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to detect keypresses after pressing a '%' in jquery? What I want is that after a user presses '%', the script will start detecting all keypresses after that, search through a list for matches and will stop when the user clicks on a list item in that list.

```
 $(iframeDocument).find('body').on('keypress', function(event) {
    if(event.which === 37) {
      $('#tokens-menu dd').trigger("click");
    } else {
      // search through a list
      $(iframeDocument).find('body').handleBackspace(event); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: I don't think cross domain or cross frame requests work.

Comment: @PraveenKumar they can but from past experience it's not always reliable (browser-dependent settings) and difficult to set up. From memory you have to set access policies or something to that effect. Haven't looked into it in a few years so not sure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable when you detect the `%`, and then process all keypresses after that. When they click the button, clear the variable.

```js
var percent_pressed = false;
$(window).on('keypress', function() {
  var key = event.which;
  if (percent_pressed) {
    // use this keypress
    $("#output").append(String.fromCharCode(key));
  } else if (key == 37) {
    percent_pressed = true;
    $("#output").empty();
  }
});
$("#tokens-menu").click(function() {
  percent_pressed = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Type % to start appending to output</h4>
Output: <span id="output"></span>
<br>
<button id="tokens-menu">Click to restart</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example based on your description:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which) // or e.keyCode;
    if (logging) {
        rec.push(c);
    }

    // start logging if '%' pressed
    if (e.shiftKey && e.which == 53) { 
        logging = true;
    }
});
```

See it running here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/kuotty5v/

After pressing '%' it will start recording what you are typing. You can click the "Display recorded" button to find out what is recorded so far.
I hope it helps t build your solution from this.